# Calling a ViewModel's property from another ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a ViewModel (X) with a dataGrid and a button. The grid's selecteditem is binded to this:

```
private User _SelectedPerson;
public User SelectedPerson
{
    get { return _SelectedPerson; }
    set
    {
        _SelectedPerson = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange("SelectedPerson");
    }
}
```

The button is running the following command:

```
SelectedPerson = null;
```

It's working fine. I select a row, I click the button, the selection is gone as wanted.

I now want to call the exact same function from another viewmodel (Y) using a button, I did the following:

```
  public YViewModel LoginVM { get; private set; }

   public XViewModel()
     {          
         LoginVM = new YViewModel();
     }

    public void Changing() // this is binded to the button's command (on Y's view model)
            {

                LoginVM.SelectedPerson = null;
            }
```

Nothing happens when I click the button.

Comment: Is the `LoginVM` *property* what you are actually binding to or are you perhaps using a different instance? It needs to be the same instance your View is binding to.

Comment: It wasn't the same instance indeed. Thank you!